# How can I get first x occurrences from given xml using xsl

Tags: xslt, xpath

How can I get first x occurrences on line elements from the below xml using xslt

Below is a sample xml

```
 <document>
    <line>
        <name>MAR111</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </line>

    <line>
        <name>MAR111</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MEA111</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MPR111</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MEA111</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MPR111</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </line>
</document>
```

For instance if I want first 3 occurrences the result should be

```
 <document>
    <line>
        <name>MAR111</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </line>

    <line>
        <name>MAR111</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </line>
    <line>
        <name>MEA111</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </line>
 </document>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the `postition()`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|line[3 >= position()]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/line[not(position() > $x)]
```

where `$x` must be a variable containing the wanted number of "first" elements to be selected.

Or, `$x` can be replaced with the desired number itself.

**Do note**:

This problem is a pure XPath problem and as such has a pure XPath solution -- XSLT isn't necessary at all.